# Declaring a global shared javascript variable on IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

I have separate scripts on my website: main script, plugins etc. It works fine on newer version of web browsers including IE but my problem is it doesn't work on IE7.

**default.aspx**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var mySystem = {
    vars : {
        test : 3
    },
    fn : {
        test : function() { return true }
    }
}
</script>
<script src='js/another.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

**another.js**

```
var global = mySystem;
alert(global.vars.test);
```

The error points on another.js:

> Unable to get property 'vars' of undefined or null reference

I'm thinking of combining all scripts in one but maybe there are workarounds to make this possible.
I also tried adding ***window.global = mySystem;*** on **default.aspx** script but it doesn't work either.

Comment: How do yoyu know that another.js is running after the first script?

Comment: I tried adding `alert('another.js is running');` on the first line of the script and it prompts. Then that error pops out. And besides, I won't get that error if it doesn't run, right?

Comment: The error message is telling you that *global* resolves to *undefined*. Try changing the name of that variable.